# How to form XML Nodes in Case staement

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

SQL query

```
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN a.ClubNumber IS NULL OR a.ClubNumber = ''
           THEN ''
           ELSE (b.cityname + b.statename + 
                 RTRIM(CAST(b.zipcodevalue AS VARCHAR(10))) + b.countryname)
     END) AS 'billing_info'
FROM 
    dbo.CustomerList a 
LEFT JOIN
    [dbo].[Subscribptions] c on RTRIM(a.LocationID) = c.LocationId
FOR XML PATH('subscription'), ROOT('subscriptions')
```

This has no error.

But **what I need** is when the ClubNumber is not Null then I need XML Nodes as below.

```
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN a.ClubNumber IS NULL OR a.ClubNumber = ''
           THEN ''
           ELSE (b.cityname AS 'account/billing_info/city',
                 b.statename AS 'account/billing_info/state',
                 RTRIM(CAST(b.zipcodevalue AS VARCHAR(10))) AS 'account/billing_info/zip',
                 b.countryname as 'account/billing_info/country'
FROM 
    dbo.CustomerList a 
LEFT JOIN
    [dbo].[Subscribptions] c on RTRIM(a.LocationID) = c.LocationId
FOR XML PATH('subscription'), ROOT('subscriptions')
```

But this is throwing a syntax error.

How can I format the columns XML nodes as mentioned?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is you're trying to achieve all the the results in one `CASE` **expression** (CASE statements don't exist in SQL Server). If you need 4 results you need 4 `CASE` expressions. When using `FOR XML PATH` an attribute won't be displayed if it has a value of `NULL`.

Comment: Within your `ELSE` you are using a table alias `b` but I cannot see its source. Please try to set up a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subselect `FOR XML ... TYPE`. That way the partial XML of the subselect can be used as a part of the XML in the outer query.

```
...
CASE
  WHEN a.clubnumber IS NULL
        OR a.clubnumber = '' THEN
    ''
  ELSE
    (SELECT b.cityname "account/billing_info/city",
            b.statename "account/billing_info/state",
            rtrim(cast(b.zipcodevalue AS varchar(10))) "account/billing_info/zip",
            b.countryname "account/billing_info/country"
            FOR XML PATH(''),
                    TYPE)
END
...
```